# Using filters inside a external symbol

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I'm trying to use a external symbol with a filter. Unfortunately it looks like the browsers don't support this feature.

Am I declaring it wrong or hasn't it been implemented?

Example page: http://www.lisa.ink/svg/

Chrome only shows the last svg
Firefox shows the first and second svg as expected
Safari only shows the last svg as expected

**1. Using external symbol with only a fragment identifier**

html:

```
<svg>
    <use xlink:href="/svg/rect.svg#rect" />
</svg>
```

external svg:

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <filter id="hueRotate">
       <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="hueRotate" values="90" result="A"/>
    </filter>
    <symbol id="rect"  viewBox="0 0 640 550">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="red" filter="url(#hueRotate)" />
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

**2. Using a external symbol with a full IRI**

html:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <use xlink:href="/svg/rect.svg#rectWithFullUrl" />
</svg>
```

external svg:

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <filter id="hueRotate">
       <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="hueRotate" values="90" result="A"/>
    </filter>
    <symbol id="rectWithFullUrl"  viewBox="0 0 640 550">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="red" filter="url(/svg/rect.svg#hueRotate)" />
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

**3. Using a external symbol with local**

html:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <use xlink:href="/svg/rect.svg#rectWithMissingFilter" />
</svg>


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <filter id="missingHueRotate">
            <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="hueRotate" values="90" result="A"/>
        </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

external svg:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="rectWithMissingFilter"  viewBox="0 0 640 550">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="red" filter="url(#missingHueRotate)" />
    </symbol>
  </def>
</svg>
```

Comment: Those symbols aren't inside a defs element. That's the first thing I found wrong. And please POST YOUR CODE. Digging around in view source is a time was.

Comment: I improved my question and source files a bit.  Officially the defs element only blocks the internal elements from rendering and therefore it's not required, only recommended. But I changed it and surprisingly the 1st svg changed inside Firefox to the expected form.

Comment: Only 1 and 2 should work. 3 would be a bug (and is a known Chrome bug) as the url reference is local i.e. should only match within the file itself.